# C++ Runtime Error: free(): invalid next size (fast)

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, memory-management, runtime-error

I have seen mutliple posts about this error, however I have not been able to find a solution. In my code I have a vector of "Gene"s and each gene contains a source and destination in the form of an int.

I want to create a vector of ints that contains all of the different possible values of the source and destination in the vector of genes. I begin by going through each gene and identify the source and destination and then check if that ID already exists in the vector. If it does, then ignore it, but if its a new value then add it to the vector.

```
void addMutations(vector<Gene*>* genome){
    vector<int> nodeIDs;

    for(int i = 0; i < genome->size(); i++){
        int src = genome->at(i)->sourceNeuronID;
        int dst = genome->at(i)->destinationNeuronID;

        if(find(nodeIDs.begin(), nodeIDs.end(), src) == nodeIDs.end()){
            nodeIDs.push_back(src);// <-- Issue is here
        } 

        if(find(nodeIDs.begin(), nodeIDs.end(), dst) == nodeIDs.end()){
            nodeIDs.push_back(dst);// <-- Probably here too
        } 
}
```

Does the issue come from the fact that `src` and `dst` go out of scope at the end of iteration of the `for` loop?

Comment: "The issue" would be... what? The error message in the title? I don't see how a `push_back` into a vector of ints could give that error (as there is no `free()` involved in any way).

Comment: This typically happens when you write out of bounds of allocated memory. My suggestion is that you stop using pointers so much. Instead of passing a pointer to the vector, pass a reference. And instead of having a vector of pointers, have a vector of instances (unless you need pointers for polymorphism, which you don't seem to be using). Also, instead of a vector for the node ids, it seems you could use a [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set).

Comment: Youn need to create a [MCVE]

Comment: to your question `Does the issue come from the fact that src and dst go out of scope at the end of iteration of the for loop?` no, compiler will allocate the src and dst before for loop and your use of `src` and `dst` is within the scope of the variable. And error is not in the `push_back()` call, its from iterator, check your `genome` vector is initialized properly

Comment: The `push_back` function of a vector adds a *copy* of `src` / `dst` to the vector. What happens to `src` / `dst` after the push is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the issue come from the fact that `src` and `dst` go out of scope at the end of iteration of the for loop?

No, these valuea are pushed into the vector, before going out of scope, so this is fine.

> C++ Runtime Error: free(): invalid next size (fast)

This means that heap is corrupted. Valgrind can be helpful in this cases.

That memory error is not coming from `std::vector`, but from your pointers. Somewhere, you free something you shouldn't? That may be caused by bad memory allocation on your behalf (something has not been allocated as you desire it to). Who knows with the code you posted.

In any, case, *you should really use Valgrind to track that error down*.

---

PS: Do you really need to use that many pointers? I mean in your functions, you could just have passed your vector by reference, like this:

```
void addMutations(vector<Gene*>& genome) {
```

and then do:

```
genome.at(i)->sourceNeuronID;
```

and so on.

Pointers are great (e.g. in polymorphism), but you should use them with caution and of course, use them when needed (Pan Metron Ariston).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I changed the function so that its pass by reference now because it does make more sense. What is really interesting though is that at this point in the code nothing has been free, and all the Gene objects are well defined. I will look into Valgrind for help. Thank you!

Comment: Then an allocation went wrong @MagnusCaligo. For exaple you allocated less than you needed, or didn't assign the memory properly to a pointer...Or you have a dangling pointer, or....it's a long list! ;) Don't forget to *accept* my answer, if it helped. Good luck and you are welcome!

Comment: I figured it out. I was not dedicating enough space with malloc elsewhere in my code. Hopefully someone else in the future will have found this helpful. I would extremely recommend Valgrind because within the first 15 mins of using it I found my issue.